# AuthAlreadyAssociated Exception in Django Social Auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

After I create a user using say Facebook(let's say fbuser) or Google(googleuser). If I create another user  through the normal django admin(normaluser), and try logging again using Facebook or Google while third user(normaluser) is logged in, it throws an error exception AuthAlreadyAssociated.

1. Ideally it should throw an error called you are already logged in as
   user normaluser.
2. Or it should log out normal user, and try associating with the
   account which is already associated with FB or Google, as the case
   may be.

How do I implement one of these two above features? All advice welcome.

Also when I try customizing SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE, it is not possible to login with FB or Google, and it forces the login URL /accounts/login/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DSA doesn't logout accounts (or flush sessions) at the moment. `AuthAlreadyAssociated` highlights the scenario where the current user is not associated to the current social account trying to be used. There are a couple solutions that might suite your project:

1. Define a sub-class of `social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` and override the default behavior (`process_exception()`) to redirect or setup the warning you like in the way you prefer.
2. Add a pipeline method (replacing `social_auth.backend.pipeline.social.social_auth_user`) that logouts the current user instead of raising an exception.

Comment: I tried doing option # 2 but it wasn't succeeding. It successfully logs the user out, but not back in as the new social.user.

replacing:
msg = 'This {0} account is already in use.'.format(provider)
raise AuthAlreadyAssociated(strategy.backend, msg)

with:
logout(kwargs.get('request'))
user = social.user

Comment: @omab: On python social auth using Django, how would I seamlessly in the same request log out current user and set up session for second user using the social_user pipeline replacement?

Comment: @omab: In social.actions.do_complete, is_authenticated is set in the beginning based on existing user ("user A"). But if I log out "user A" in the pipeline and return "user B", do_complete will not log in "user B" because it is_authenticated was already set True. Should do_complete re-evaluate the session user again after the pipeline is complete to determine whether to login "user B"?

Answer (score 5):

My approach to this problem was a little different, instead of tackling this in the pipeline, I made sure that a user was never passed into the pipeline in the first place. This way, even if the social_auth.user does not match the logged in user, the social_auth.user will be logged in on top of the currently logged in user.

I think it's as easy as overriding the `complete` action.

urls.py

```py
path('complete/<str:backend>/', 'account.views.complete', name='complete'),
```

account/views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from social_core.actions import do_complete
from social_django.utils import psa
from social_django.views import _do_login

@never_cache
@csrf_exempt
@psa('social:complete')
def complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
    """Override this method so we can force user to be logged out."""
    return do_complete(request.backend, _do_login, user=None,
                       redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, request=request,
                       *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Somewhere over time, my earlier solution does not seem to work properly anymore, perhaps with the latest python social auth. In any event, your solution does work properly, and is certainly simpler than mine. I've deleted mine from this question. Thanks.

Comment: This is not working (as is) because the original `complete` view changed slightly. I had to dive in the source and tweak it a bit to match the changes, but the strategy is solid, override the user param  unconditionally passing None.

Comment: the latest working (0.3.x version) version of the complete function for me https://maketips.net/tip/450/fix-authalreadyassociated-at-complete-this-account-is-already-in-use

Answer (score 5):

Solution for people wondering how to override social_user pipeline under python-social-auth version 3+

**In your settings.py:**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    # Path to your overrided method
    # You can set any other valid path.
    'myproject.apps.python-social-auth-overrided.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

**In your overrided social_user**:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def social_user(backend, uid, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    provider = backend.name
    social = backend.strategy.storage.user.get_social_auth(provider, uid)
    if social:
        if user and social.user != user:
            logout(backend.strategy.request)
        elif not user:
            user = social.user
    return {'social': social,
            'user': user,
            'is_new': user is None,
            'new_association': False}
```

You can delete commented lines if you want.

Comment: your approach is logging out the current user. But it is not logging in the newly authenticated user. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I solved it by inserting below code in settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    '...',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    '...',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    '...',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    '...',
)
```

Comment: Not sure, its not an invalid answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is:

1. Define a class that inherits from `SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware`
2. Implement the method `process_exception`,
3. Add the implemented class to `MIDDLEWARE` list on **`settings.py`**.

In **`middleware.py`**, which should be in your apps's directory, i.e., same directory of your `views.py` file associated with your app, define the following class:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from social_core.exceptions import AuthAlreadyAssociated

class FacebookAuthAlreadyAssociatedMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    """Redirect users to desired-url when AuthAlreadyAssociated exception occurs."""
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, AuthAlreadyAssociated):
            if request.backend.name == "facebook":
                message = "This facebook account is already in use."
                if message in str(exception):
                    # Add logic if required

                    # User is redirected to any url you want
                    # in this case to "app_name:url_name"
                    return redirect(reverse("app_name:url_name"))
```

In **`settings.py`**, add the implemented class to the `MIDDLEWARE` list:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Some Django middlewares
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware",

    # the middleware you just implemented
    "app_name.middleware.FacebookAuthAlreadyAssociatedMiddleware",
]
```

This solved my problem, and I was able to handle the flow of control when the `AuthAlreadyAssociated` exception was raised.