# How to handle AuthAlreadyAssociated at Python-auth/Django-Social?

Tags: python, django, facebook, twitter, oauth

I use this [python-social-auth/social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) to connect my web with social media
I want to ask how to handle errors when the same account is used to sign up?

For example, I signed up using facebook and I signed up again using twitter. both successfully registered into two separate accounts, when I logged in using my facebook and then on my account settings page, I want to connect my twitter that has been registered before it will display an error message

**"AuthAlreadyAssociated at / oauth / complete / twitter /"**

[AuthAlreadyAssociated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNOp1.png)

This message appears after I authorize on the twitter redirect page when it gets redirected back to my web.

In short, how to deal with accounts that have been registered in other accounts?

This is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def settings(request):
    user = request.user
    try:
        github_login = user.social_auth.get(provider='github')
    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        github_login = None

    try:
        twitter_login = user.social_auth.get(provider='twitter')
    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        twitter_login = None

    try:
        facebook_login = user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook')
    except UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist:
        facebook_login = None

    can_disconnect = (user.social_auth.count() > 1 or 
    user.has_usable_password())

    return render(request, 'profile/settings.html', {
        'github_login': github_login,
        'twitter_login': twitter_login,
        'facebook_login': facebook_login,
        'can_disconnect': can_disconnect
    })
```

And this is my settings.html template:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Navhi Microblog - Profile{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
    <br />
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            {% include 'profile/base_profile.html' %}
                
                <!--Card Body goes here-->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% if github_login %}
                                {% if can_disconnect %}
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'github' %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Disconnect from GitHub</button>
                                    </form>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color: red">You must <a href="{% url 'password' %}">define a password</a> for your account before disconnecting from Github.</<p class="text-center">
                                {% endif %}
                            {% else %}
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-social btn-github btn-block" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
                                    <span class="fa fa-github"></span> Connect to Github
                                </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% if twitter_login %}
                                {% if can_disconnect %}
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'twitter' %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Disconnect from Twitter</button>
                                    </form>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color: red">You must <a href="{% url 'password' %}">define a password</a> for your account before disconnecting from Twitter.</p>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% else %}
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-social btn-twitter btn-block" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
                                    <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Connect to Twitter
                                </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% if facebook_login %}
                                {% if can_disconnect %}
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'facebook' %}">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Disconnect from Facebook</button>
                                    </form>
                                {% else %}
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color: red">You must <a href="{% url 'password' %}">define a password</a> for your account before disconnecting from Facebook.</p>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% else %}
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-social btn-facebook btn-block" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
                                    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Connect to Facebook
                                </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you, I hope somebody can provide a solution for this, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been answered here: 
[AuthAlreadyAssociated Exception in Django Social Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018147/authalreadyassociated-exception-in-django-social-auth)

Basically the answer is to override the default method `process_exception()` in the `social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` class, and add this middleware to your settings.py.

More on how to override here: [How do I handle exceptions on Python Social Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305986/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-on-python-social-auth)